# How to specify swagger parameter "format" using rest dsl?

Tags: java, apache-camel, swagger

Im using apache camel to create a rest service. hope to solve the issue with creating a partition "format" swagger. expect to:

```
 "/action" : {
      "get" : {
        "summary" : "summary",
        "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "updatedate",
          "in" : "query",
          "description" : "description",
          "required" : false,
          "type" : "string",
          "format":"date"
        }]
```

but this code:

```
rest().description("description").produces("application/json")
     .get("/action").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).description("description").outTypeList(qwe.class)    

.param().type(RestParamType.query).description("description").dataType("string").name("updatedate").required(false).endParam()
```

generates swagger without **"format":"date"** section:

```
 "/action" : {
      "get" : {
        "summary" : "summary",
        "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "updatedate",
          "in" : "query",
          "description" : "description",
          "required" : false,
          "type" : "string"            
        }]
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: @ClausIbsen 2.17.1

Comment: Try with latest release and see if we have it there

Comment: @SergeyMelnikov, Did you able to find any solution? I am using latest camle version 2.20.0 still format is not available.

Comment: @ClausIbsen, Can you please suggest? I m using latest camel version still not able to add format in swagger json.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported, so I have logged a ticket to make this possible in next release. You can follow this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11991